# Kivy args_converter function: 'ValueError' after trying to build ListView item with kwargs

Tags: python, listview, kivy

I'm studying how to build custom ListView items in a widget along with writing args_converter function. My problem is simple: I built a custom BoxLayout  with some properties:

```
class CountyItem(BoxLayout):
    background = ObjectProperty
    name_gui = StringProperty
    protocol_gui = StringProperty
    quantity_gui = NumericProperty
    unit_gui = NumericProperty
    budget_gui = NumericProperty
```

Then I created a widget (another BoxLayout) with a ListView as an ObjectProperty (here's the [complete code](http://pastebin.com/C3sU2p9A)):

```
class CountyView(BoxLayout):
    county_list_view = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(CountyView, self).__init__()
        print("CountyView created!")
        self.county_list_view.adapter.data = ["Municipio1", "Municipio2", "Municipio3", "Municipio4"]
        print("ListAdapter created!")

    def county_converter(self, index, datakey):
        print("In county_converter....")
        print("datakey:"+ str(datakey))
        print("index:"+ str(index))
        app = ConsManage.get_running_app()

        result = {}

        if index % 2:
            result['background'] = (0, 0, 0, 1)
        else:
            result['background'] = (0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 1)

        result['name_gui'] = datakey
        result['protocol_gui'] = app.data[datakey]['protocol']
        result['quantity_gui'] = app.data[datakey]['quantity']
        result['unit_gui'] = app.data[datakey]['unit']
        result['budget_gui'] = app.data[datakey]['budget']
        print("result = " + str(result))

        return result
```

In my Kivy file, I defined the customization of both widgets, along with the definition
of the ListAdapter for the CountyItem widget:

```
#:import listadpt kivy.adapters.listadapter 
#:import mydata __main__

CountyView:

<CountyView>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size_hint_y: None
    county_list_view: list_view
    ListView:
        id:list_view
        adapter:
            listadpt.ListAdapter(data=[],
            cls=mydata.CountyItem,
            args_converter=root.county_converter)

<CountyItem>:
    size_hint_y: None
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            #rgba: self.background 
            rgba: (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size    
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_x: 2
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text:  root.name_gui
            color: (0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0)
            font_size: "15dp"
            size_hint_y: 0.45
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.55
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                text:  root.protocol_gui
                color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
                font_size: "13dp"
                size_hint_x: 0.3
            Label:
                text:  str(root.quantity_gui)
                color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
                font_size: "13dp"
                size_hint_x: 0.1
            Label:
                text:  str(root.unit_gui)
                color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
                font_size: "13dp"
                size_hint_x: 0.2
            Label:
                text:  str(root.budget_gui)
                color: (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
                font_size: "13dp"
                size_hint_x: 0.2
```

When I run the code, I checked if the 'result' of the county_converter is being correctly assigned with each kwargs of the CountyItem item. The result is the following:

`result = {'protocol_gui': '00000001', 'budget_gui': 1000000, 'quantity_gui': 100, 'background': (0.05, 0.05, 0.07, 1), 'unit_gui': 10000, 'name_gui': 'Municipio1'}`

However, as soon as the window is created it closes and shows this message:

`ValueError: Label.text accept only str`

The complete execution and backtrace is [here](http://pastebin.com/jVu3sev4).

Anyway, what might be causing this problem? Which actions should I take to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bionoid pointed out the answer just after you left irc; your properties are declared wrong. You need to instantiate the property with (e.g.) `background = ObjectProperty()`.

This explains your error; the label's text is set to point at the ObjectProperty (as in, the base class), not the string it expects.

Comment: Thanks inclement. I saw his answer at IRC and corrected right along. I would add that my kv file generated window was ugly, so if anyone test it, they should remove the "size_hint_y: None" rule at the CountyView and CountyItem, since it shows the layout unproperly.